# OpenGeo Suite SDK authenticate

Tags: boundless-suite, authentication, sdk

I am using the OpenGeo suite Snapshot 2.2 I have rules in GeoServer that display layers to certain users, and only allow editing to certain layers by certain users. This works fine when using GeoExplorer, the user must login to see the layerrs / edit, but when using the SDK I get no login box, meaning the user stays anonymous which prevents editing.

I read [HERE, OpenGeo SDK insturctions](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/sdk-api/lib/widgets/Viewer.html) that in the gxp.viewer I can add `authenticate`? Is this what I need to add to bring the login dialogue up? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement something similar to the authenticate method in GeoExplorer in your SDK viewer:

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/app/static/script/app/GeoExplorer/Composer.js#L272:L369

but this depends on some server-side JS pieces as well:

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/app/auth.js

basically it's hitting the GeoServer spring authentication endpoint.