# Implementing GeoExplorer login functionality in a OpenGeo Suite App

Tags: sdk, authentication, boundless-suite

I’m trying to implement the same type of login functionality that is available in GeoExplorer. I gather from the answer to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73008/opengeo-suite-sdk-authenticate) question that there are at least a few files needed. On the client side I’ve added the following [lines](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/app/static/script/app/GeoExplorer/Composer.js#L272:L373)
, which seems to work OK (the login window is displayed when clicking on the login button).

The error I get when clicking on the button to sumbit the user/password is the following (running the app using debug with client side SDK):

*`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:9080/login/"`*

So obviously I’m missing some code/configuration. From the thread I linked to, it says auth.js is needed for the server side, but I’m not sure how to set it up properly. I'm using version 3.1 of the suite.

What am I missing in order for the login to work?

Answer (score 1):

It means integrating stick into the SDK application, in order to use server-side javascript.

https://github.com/hns/stick

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/pom.xml#L79:L85

The best I can advise is to look at how this is done in GeoExplorer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'll try integrating stick and also look into GeoExplorer a bit more.