# Admin Sample GXP Viewer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers-2

I have Geospatial application which is using GXP, GeoServer, GeoExt and PostgisSQL. We would like to enhance the application by adding a user friendly Admin system, similar to what GeoNode has. This sytem would let us create and manage users and create projects specific to users.

Can someone give us a head start on how we can do this? Or any place we can download it and configure it according to our requirements.

Comment: I Did read this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73008/opengeo-suite-sdk-authenticate but I am still confused on what should be my starting point

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MapStore of Geosoluciones project based on Geoexplorer of OpenGeo. It is open source.